# two titles in fancybox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox

I'm trying to set two title box for a fancybox iframe.I'm using version 1.3.4 This i currently get.

[image]

And this is the associated source code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.group").fancybox({
            'zoomSpeedIn'           : 600,
            'zoomSpeedOut'          : 500,
            'easingIn'              : 'easeOutBack',
            'easingOut'             : 'easeInBack'

        });

$("a.iframe").fancybox({
        'titlePosition' : 'over',
            'showCloseButton'   : false,
            'titleShow'         : true,
            'scrolling'         :'no',
            'width'        : 650,
            'height'       : 660,
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'type'              : 'iframe',
            'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
            'hideOnContentClick': false,
            'enableEscapeButton': false
        });
    });
```

But I would like to have the same title box at the bottom of my lightbox without deleting the one which is at the top of it. So I created another property in the fancybox css :

```
.fancybox-title-over1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: left;
}


#fancybox-title-over1 {
    padding: 10px;
    background-image: url('mybottomtitlebackground.png');
    display: block;
}
```

But i don't know how to display it on my lightbox.

Thank you in advance for your assistance !

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle that shows the fancybox as it stands currently?  You could probably just clone the element using jquery and position it correctly, but if you can provide a fiddle it will be easier to tell.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Here is the jsfiddle : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/a65ZN/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, you can clone the title then position it at the bottom:

```
var title = $(".fancybox-title-over");
title.css({'top':'0px', 'bottom':'auto'});
var p = $(".fancybox-title-over").parent();
var x = $(".fancybox-title-over").clone();
p.append(x);
x.css({"top":"auto","bottom":"0", "position":"absolute"});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a65ZN/11/